# What is the difference between ::operator new(size_t) new and malloc?

Tags: c++, gcc

It appears to me both allocate a block of memory and return the pointer to the first byte. Any difference? I notice that GCC's allocator classes have two versions, one using ::operator new, another one using malloc.

http://gcc.gnu.org/viewcvs/gcc/trunk/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/ext/new_allocator.h?view=markup

http://gcc.gnu.org/viewcvs/gcc/trunk/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/ext/malloc_allocator.h?view=markup

(I understand that new expression and operator new are different)

Comment: What wasn't there identical question like 2 days ago max? @larsmans Ok, 5 days =)

Comment: Thanks. I vote to close this question...

Comment: It seriously didn't pop up in the automatic duplicate indicator when you post questions? The title is nearly exactly the same.